# Convert a row of images into a carousel in small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

i'm trying to convert this row of images...
[image]

Convert that into a little carousel for visualization in small devices (Responsive Desing) i'm using bootstrap, the code of that images is here:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center pb-5" style="background-image: url('assets/img/Vector_Chain1.png'); margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;">
                    <img src="assets/img/TheEye.png" class="img-fluid col-md-3 col-sm-8 mt-5 img-section2" alt="">
                    <img src="assets/img/ThePyramid.png" class="img-fluid col-md-3 col-sm-8 mt-5 img-section2" alt="">
                    <img src="assets/img/TheEthernal.png" class="img-fluid col-md-3 col-sm-8 mt-5 img-section2" alt="">
                </div>
```

I want when the device are small like a phone, this div convert itself into a carousel for a better visualization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add classes `d-block` and `d-md-flex` to your container
2. Create a new container for the carousel function on mobile.

Final `html` code:

```html
<div class="row d-none d-md-flex justify-content-center pb-5" style="background-image: url('assets/img/Vector_Chain1.png'); margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;">
  <img src="assets/img/TheEye.png" class="img-fluid col-md-3 col-sm-8 mt-5 img-section2" alt="">
  <img src="assets/img/ThePyramid.png" class="img-fluid col-md-3 col-sm-8 mt-5 img-section2" alt="">
  <img src="assets/img/TheEthernal.png" class="img-fluid col-md-3 col-sm-8 mt-5 img-section2" alt="">
</div>

<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide d-block d-md-none" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/TheEye.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/ThePyramid.png" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/ThePyramid.png" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```